# How to set height of the Winui 3 Community Toolkit DataGrid row?

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid, winui

I am trying to use CommunityToolkit.WinUI for DataGrid.
I am trying to set the custom row size however its setting up row size but its not adjusting the text inside that row as new size.
Seems like I am not doing it properly, please help and guide to set the custom row size properly.

```
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <ct:DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
                         AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                         Margin="0"   
                         HeadersVisibility="None"
                         RowHeight="20"
                         VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <!-- Setting Row Style for grid -->
                <ct:DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ct:DataGridRow">
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="20"/>
                        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20"/>   
                        <Setter Property="MaxHeight" Value="20"/>                           
                    </Style>
                </ct:DataGrid.RowStyle>                

                <!-- Setting up column -->
                <ct:DataGrid.Columns>
                    <ct:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="LineCol" Header="Line" Binding="{Binding LineNumber}" Tag="LineNumber"
                                           IsReadOnly="True" 
                                           FontSize="10">
                    </ct:DataGridTextColumn>

                    <ct:DataGridTextColumn Header="Text" Binding="{Binding TextLine}" Tag="Text"                                           
                                           FontSize="10">
                    </ct:DataGridTextColumn>
                </ct:DataGrid.Columns>
            </ct:DataGrid>
        </Grid>
```

Output:
[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwP6O.png)

I tried adjusting different values like MinHeight however doesn't seem to take effect.